# Using Excel to conditionally concatenate multiple rows

Tags: excel, loops, formulas

I have a large data file that has some broken rows from the extraction process.  I'm trying to clean it up in excel and am running into an issue with multiple row checking.  I could nest a set amount of IF statements in my formula but that runs the risk of missing values.  A Sample of the data looks like this (The strings are pasted into Column A):

```
'ID_Value','last_name','first_name','','dob','gender'comment
comment
comment
comment'
'ID_Value','last_name','first_name','','dob','gender'comment'
'ID_Value','last_name','first_name','','dob','gender'comment'
'ID_Value','last_name','first_name','','dob','gender'comment
comment
comment
comment
comment'
```

I need to roll the comment rows into the normal row preceding them.  Currently I can identify all the rows and can make it work when there are two comment rows but going beyond that I am at a loss.

```
Formula in Column B:  =IF(LEFT(A1, 1) = "'", "IGNORE", "FLAG")
Formula in Column C:  =(IF(B2 = "FLAG", IF(B1 = "FLAG", "MOVE")))
Formula in Column D: =IF(B2 = "FLAG", IF(B1 = "FLAG", IF(C2 = "MOVE", CONCATENATE(A1, A2))))
```

Any recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you golgauth for cleaning up the output of my formulas and making it readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go this should do it.
Download the spreadsheet here.
[Spreadsheet Example](http://amicableits.com/stackexchange/excel/comment_aid.xlsm)

Paste your data into Sheet 1 Cell A1 and click the run_filter button.
Alternatively you can first run it with the dummy data that already present in Sheet1 and check to see that the results work as expected.

A couple of caveats.

1. The macro will stop When it encounter a blank cell in Column A. This is how I determine that the macro should end.
2. Comments should contain no more than 5 commas otherwise they'll be interpreted as real data.
3. A space character is added to comments.
4. The first row should not contain a comment.

A new worksheet called Filtered_Result will be created with the required result.

If you want to view the code click on the developer tab.
If it's not present  [See here for How to add it tab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/show-the-developer-tab-or-run-in-developer-mode-HA010173052.aspx)
Then Click the Macro Button.
[image: Macro Button]
Click the edit button on the macro combine_comments to see the code.
[image: edit button]

Give it a try and let me know how it goes.
Peter H

Comment: Thank you Peter H.  Your solution saved me this weekend and kept the project from going off the rails.  I have not had an opportunity to review the macro code but I plan to so I can better understand how they work for next time.